# Ubuntu 16.04 unable to connect to external hard drive

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am unable to open my external hard drive on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.
I know its detected because when I run parted, it shows me this:

[image]

I don't know what the problem is and how to solve it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the output of sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

Comment: @ubashu it gives me:-  mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist. Same for sdb

Comment: a) is there any data on it b) have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yup, I tried rebooting my Ubuntu system. It has data in it

Comment: What is the output of lvscan?

Comment: I am unable to run lvscan.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: bose@MARK-XII:~$ sudo lvscan
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.

Comment: I'm a bit buffled by the partition starting at `0.00B` - shouldn't the master boot record be somewhere in this area? BTW: On which systems does the drive work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Partition Table: loop says that there is no partition table. The file system occupies the entire disk. mount /dev/sdb  should work. **NOT** /dev/sdb1

Comment: I tried mount /dev/sdb, but it says can't find in /etc/fstab

Comment: did it work? @SubhasisBose

Comment: @dheeraj_m_pai no, it did not. I connected it to my windows system and it was working fine. I eventually did a complete format of the external HDD, after that I was able to get it connected to my Ubuntu system.